# Decide if image or prototype of a connected component is a connected component in case of continuous map

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Decide if image or prototype of a connected component is a connected component in case of continuous map

X->Y , Y is a component if X is.

Comment: *Prototype* isn’t the right word; do you mean *pre-image*?

Comment: yes, exactly, sorry for my english:)

Comment: please, can you help

Comment: HINT: What do you know about $f[C]$ when $C$ is connected and $f$ is continuous? \\ Every function from any space to the one-point space is continuous, and the one-point space is connected; what does this tell you about continuous pre-images of connected sets?

Comment: it is connected?

Comment: Yes, if you’re asking about $f[C]$: one of the first theorems about connected sets is that the continuous image of a connected set is connected. Components are connected, so if $C$ is a component of $X$, then $f[C]$ is a connected subset of $Y$.

Comment: could you give an example with some easy sets

Comment: An example for which part?

Comment: so image of component of connectivity is not a component of connectivity in case of continuous map?

Comment: oh, i mean IS but not IS NOT

Comment: because the answer to this problem in my book is NO

Comment: and idk why so here

Comment: and I think it is a UNITION of components

Answer (score 1):

The continuous image of a connected component of $X$ will be connected, but it need not be a **component** of $Y$. The continuous pre-image of a connected component of $Y$ need not even be connected. Let $X=\Bbb Z$ and $Y=\Bbb R$, both with the usual topology, and let $f:X\to Y$ be the constant function $f(n)=0$; this will give you both counterexamples.

Comment: oh i got, but here is what i need: will  an image of component be component

Comment: and I see that not

Comment: @AngelaDevis: Take a look at the example that I suggested. What are the components of $Z$? Their images are all $\{0\}$; is that a component of $\Bbb R$?

Comment: components of Z i think are 0 1 2 etc

Comment: @AngelaDevis: If you mean $\{0\},\{1\},\{2\}$, and so on (and of course also $\{-1\},\{-2\},\ldots$, you’re right: each of the singletons (one-point sets) is a component of $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: and the final one: Prove that pre-image of connected component in case of continuous map in a UNITION of connected components